# How do I use belongs_to and has_many correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have been debugging this the entire day. 
I have two models in my application: teaClass & tea. In teaclass.rb, I have

```
has_many :teas
```

In tea.rb, I have 'belongs_to :teaclass`.

I try to make the url looks like this `"..teaclasses/:id/teas/:id";` so in `teas_controller.rb`, I put `before_filter :get_teaClass`

```
def show
@tea = @teaclass.teas.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @tea }
end
end

def new
if @teaclass.teas
    @tea = @teaclass.teas.new
    @teaclass.teas << @tea 
    #@tea = Tea.new
    else
        flash[:notice=>"failed"]
        @tea = Tea.new 
        @teaclass.teas << @tea 
    end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @tea }
end
end

def get_teaClass
    begin
        @teaclass = Teaclass.find(params[:teaclass_id])rescue
        redirect_to teaclass_path, :notice => "Teaclass Required!"
    end
 end
```

But I keep getting an error saying "unknown attribute: teaclass_id"

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2906:inassign_attributes'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2902:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2902:in `assign_attributes'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2474:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:380:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:380:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:380:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2178:in `with_scope'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:207:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:207:in `with_scope'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:376:in `method_missing'
/home/jianpchen/repo/Teashop/app/controllers/teas_controller.rb:31:in `new'
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Make sure all your code is correct, I edited the heck out of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I try to make the url looks like this "..teaclasses/:id/teas/:id"; so in teas_controller.rb, I put before_filter :get_teaClass

This only matters if you are trying to get nested routes setup but id doesn't sound like you are doing that.

What you need to do is actually add the foreign id to the database. So check `schema.rb` and make sure that column exists.

## Here is what you need to do.

1. Make sure you actually have the foreign in the database table `tea`.
2. If you do skip to the next step where I will show you a better way to write your code.
3. If you do not have 'tea_class_id' as an integer value on your 'tea' table you need to add it.
4. script/generate migration add_tea_class_id_to_tea
5. rake db:migrate
6. Now This is how your code should be written

## routes.rb

```
map.resources :teas
map.resources :teas_classes
```

## Models

models/tea.rb

```
class Tea < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tea_class
end
```

tea_class.rb

```
class TeaClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teas
end
```

## controllers

teas_controller.rb

```
def new
   @tea = Tea.new
end

def show
  @tea = tea.find(params[:id)
end

def create
    @tea = Tea.new(params[:tea])
    if @tea.save
        redirect_to teas_path
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

## views

This is really important. Make sure you are passing the :tea_class_id as a parameter when you create a tea otherwise it doesn't know how to make the association. It's kinda behind the stage because you send `params[:tea]` but it is in those parameters where the `tea_class_id` is actually sent.

So... in your view you need to have some sort of way for users to choose a category or as you have it tea class and that is usually done with a select box when it is a one to many association.

new.html.erb

```
<% form_for(@tea) do |t| %>
    <%= t.collection_select :tea_class_id TeaClass.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

Make sure you have tea classes to actually fill the `collection_select` method. Google that plus rails api if you don't get what's going on.

## Nested Routes (on the side)

Looked like you were trying to get the routes like `teaclasses/:id/teas/:id`. This is called nested routing and you will want to set that up in your routes.rb

```
map.resources :tea_classes_ do |tea_classes|
   tea_classes :teas
end
map.resources :teas
```

Then you can link to `teas_classes/pour/teas/chinese`. You should know this command `rake routes`. It will help you understand how the paths work.

But if you just want the link to get going it should be like this:

```
<%= link_to "Teas", tea_classes_teas_path(@tea_class)%>
```

You need to supply `@teas` do the link because it takes the id from that and when you click it gives it to the `teas_controller' as`params[:teas_class_id]`. You don't need to do anything without. It will automatically be in the url.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps. I don't have the foreign key in the Tea table, that's the main problem. I scaffolded my model and typed in "has_many" and "belongs_to" in the associated model file. I assumed rails would do all the magic creating all the database relation. Apparently, rails doesn't do that. Also, is there a quick way to generate all the foreign keys and other stuff automatically (like scaffolding)?

Comment: script/generate scaffold name:string teas_class_id:integer

Comment: run that as a scaffold and it will generate a migration with the id you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your logs, you'll see what the params has contains. Given your code and explanation, there is not key `teaclass_id` in params. You most likely are looking for :id. If you want to access :teaclass_id, you'll probably need to set that up in your route

```
match 'controller/:teaclass_id' => 'controller#show'
```